# BPS sectors in $\cal{N}=4$ SYM

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

I am familiar with the idea of a BPS bound as in a lower limit on the mass of supermultiplets given by a certain function of the central charge and when I think of $\cal{N}=4$ SYM I see a complicated lagrangian in my mind.

Somehow the above picture seems insufficient to understand the classification of what are called "BPS sectors" in $\cal{N}=4$ SYM.

I would like to know what is the meaning and the derivation of the following listing for $\cal{N}=4$ SYM ,

- $\frac{1}{2}$ BPS sector consists of multi-trace operators involving a single bosonic operator $Z$
- $\frac{1}{4}$ BPS sector consists of multi-trace operators involving two bosonic operator $Z, Y$
- $\frac{1}{8}$ BPS sector consists of multi-trace operators involving three bosonic operator $Z, Y, X$ and two fermionic operators $\lambda$, $\bar{\lambda}$

(everything above is apparently assumed to be in the the Lie algebra of $U(N)$)

I would also like to know what is the relation between the above classification and thinking in terms of short/semi-short/long multiplets.

I would be happy to know of expository references for the above topics. I haven't been able to locate any on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BPS conditions in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM is just another name for the shortening conditions in the $psu(2,2|4)$ symmetry algebra of the theory. This algebra has 32 odd generators: 16 supercharges $Q_{\alpha a}$ and $\tilde{Q}_{\dot{\alpha}}^a$ and 16 superconformal charges $S^a_\alpha$ and $\tilde{S}_{\dot\alpha a}$. Here the indices $\alpha,\dot\alpha=1,2$ are Weyl spinor indices and $a=1,\dotsc,4$ is an index in the fundamental representation of the $SU(4)$ R-symmetry group. The generators $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ have dimension $-1/2$ and hence annihilates a primary state. The highest weight state of a BPS multiplet is furthermore annihilated by one or more of the supercharges. In particular a $\frac{1}{2}$-BPS state, or chiral primary, is annihilated by half of the charges $Q$ and $\tilde{Q}$. Similarly $\frac{1}{4}$-BPS ($\frac{1}{8}$-BPS) states are annihilated by a quarter (an eighth) of these charges. The exact details of what fields make up the operators in the various subsectors of course depend on the choice of simple roots (or lowering/raising operators) in the algebra, but the notation in the question seems fairly standard.

The details of the symmetry algebra should be covered in any review of $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM or the AdS/CFT-correspondence. See eg arXiv:1012.3938, which however only discusses the planar theory where only single trace operators are relevant. From an algebra point of view the more general case should however be essentially the same.

Comment: @Olof Thanks for the reply. Can you check your arxiv reference ? I think there is some typo. May be you can paste the link to the paper you are referring to. Can you also introduce yourself ? :) Nothing about you is written in your profile!

Comment: @Anirbit: Yes sorry there is a typo in the reference, it was supposed to [1012.3983](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3983). I've added some basic info to my profile. Thanks for the reminder. I also noted that your profile is kind of empty as well :)

Comment: @Olof I am a bit confused about what you are defining as a "primary". I thought a primary by definition something which is annihilated by all the $Q$s and the $S$s. Am I wrong? Also in your notation when you write $S^a _\alpha$ and $\tilde{Q}^a _\dot{\alpha}$ is there a notion of which index comes first? $a$ or $\alpha$ ? I am hoping that the review you linked to is beginner friendly and will explain what I am confused about! I haven't seen these stuff's exposition anywhere.

Comment: @Olof Can you say something about the "physics" of thinking in terms of half, quarter or one-eighth BPS sectors? Is there a clear representation theoretic way of understanding that ?

Comment: @Olof Anyway about some information about me - I am just completing masters and these kind of stuff are what I have been doing for my master's project. I shall be starting graduate school/PhD in this coming Fall. So who is your advisor?  Where are you going for your post-doc ? You write papers by the name Olof ?

Comment: @Anirbit: A primary operator is annihilated by the $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ charges. If it was also annihilated by all the $Q$:s it would never have any super-partners! It is moreover annihilated by the special conformal charges $K$.

In my answer I was just using one common convention for the indices on the charges. The details are not important for understanding the BPS operators, but I think they are the same as in the review I linked to.

Comment: @Anirbit: On representation theory: Yes, the BPS operators transform in shortened representations of $psu(2,2|4)$, since the highest weight state (or primary) is annihilated by one or more of the lowering operators.

Comment: @Olof Thanks for the explanations. That Minahan's review article is just awesome! It cleared a lot of my doubts. That does explain this point that if an operators is annihilated by $S$ and $\bar{S}$ then it is also annihilated by $K_\mu$ and hence it will be called a "chiral primary". I wonder if the converse is true ? Is every chiral primary also annihilated by $S$ and $\bar{S}$ ?

Comment: @Olof I have some more questions from that review. I will put them up on a separate question soon. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Anirbit: No, every *primary* operator is annihilated by $S$ and $\tilde{S}$, and hence also by $K$. A *chiral primary* operator is in addition also annihilated by half of the supercharges $Q$.

Comment: @Olof Sorry for the typo! I wanted to ask whether all primary operators are annihilated by $S$ and $\bar{S}$ ?

Comment: @Olof I have given away the 50 points bounty to you. Thanks a lot for the help! Hopefully you will reply again to the further questions about the Minahan's review.